# fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value, Get json error swift

Tags: objective-c, json, macos, cocoa, swift

[image]

**Get json error**

I am getting the error `fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value` when I try to return the `json`:

```
func getJson (str:NSString) -> AnyObject{

    var proxiesURL = NSURL(string:str)
    var proxiesDataJson = NSData.dataWithContentsOfURL(proxiesURL, options: NSDataReadingOptions.DataReadingUncached, error: nil)
    var json: AnyObject!

    if (proxiesDataJson != nil ){
        json = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(proxiesDataJson, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.AllowFragments, error: nil) as AnyObject
    }
    return json
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I assume the question is "what am I doing wrong".

Your function returns AnyObject (non-optional, thus cannot be nil). You declared `json` as AnyObject! (implicitly unwrapped optional - it may be nil, but you promise to compiler that it will have non-nil value). And yet `json` is nil when you attempt to return it - either  code at `json = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData` line wasn't executed, or `NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData` returned nil.

Answer (score 0):

You used ! with optional object which should be used only when you have checked its not nil, else it will crash.
Instead you should wrap it with ? instead of !. It won't crash and you don't have to check for nil.